# How to scroll to top of a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I have a gridview inside a div.. I want to scroll to top of the div from the bottom of the div using jquery.. Any suggestion..

```
<div id="GridDiv">
// gridview inside..
</div>
```

My gridview will have custom pagination generated link buttons in it... I will scroll to top of the div from the bottom of the link button click ...

```
protected void Nav_OnClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lb1 = (LinkButton)sender;
        //string s = lb1.ID;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(lb1, typeof(LinkButton), 
 "scroll", "javascript:document.getElementById('GridDiv').scrollTop = 0;", true);
```

In the place of javascript, I ll call the jquery function... Any suggestion...

**EDIT:**

Exactly like Stackoverflow questions per user page... When changing page nos it scrolls to top with smooth effect... I want to achieve that...

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but why don't you just use page anchors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use:

```
<div id="GridDiv">
// gridview inside...
</div>

<a href="#GridDiv">Scroll to top</a>
```

Comment: You don't need the anchors. Just go to #GridDiv.

Comment: +1 for a technically brilliant solution to the problem of the user... but completely useless to anyone looking for an answer to the actual question.  (Anchors does NOT solve my issue, I need to scroll the screen to the top of a div using javascript!  -- Complaining because this was top google result for me)

Comment: @RonLugge In that case, Greg Mathews' answer could help. Try setting or animating the `scrollTop` property.

Comment: @AtesGoral Yeah, I wound up doing that -- and he's getting the upvote for it (though I don't like that type of 'cramped' code style).  It just amuses and annoys me that the 'top answer' doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @RonLugge I'm with you on the "cramped" bit. So I edited his answer to add some white space.

Comment: There goes 20 lines of JavaScript. How have I never heard of this?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, this doesn't 'scroll to' an element, it directly anchors to it.

Comment: @NathanHornby Can you elaborate? What else does clicking an anchor to an element do?

Comment: @Ates Goral It takes you directly to it. There is no 'scrolling' involved. (It's a semantics discussion, but in this case a relevant one)

Comment: @NathanHornby Oh, I see. The OP has even edited the question to add "scrolls to top with smooth effect". In that case, yeah, this minimal solution wouldn't help with that.

Answer (score 194):

Here is what you can do using jquery:

```
$('#A_ID').click(function (e) { //#A_ID is an example. Use the id of your Anchor
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#DIV_ID').offset().top - 20 //#DIV_ID is an example. Use the id of your destination on the page
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: @citress The hard coded value is so that the top of the div is not at the very top of the browser window, purely for aesthetics. (Should probably leave it out)

Comment: @GregMathews "Should probably leave it out", yet every time I've done this, I have had to add the offset to ensure it is a working, professional execution. +1 just for including the offset.

Answer (score 66):

Or, for less code, inside your click you place:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

$('#DIV_ID').scrollTop(0);

}, 500);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in jQuery 2.2.0. But the answer with 116 votes does.

Comment: You have to add a `setTimeout` to make it work: `setTimeout(function )( { $('#DIV_ID').scrollTop(0); }, 500);`

Comment: Thanks London, I'll edit then, seems like things have changed

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. It should be: `setTimeout(function() { $('#DIV_ID').scrollTop(0); }, 500);`

Answer (score 5):

Special thanks to Stoic for

```
   $("#miscCategory").animate({scrollTop: $("#miscCategory").offset().top});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to scroll to the top on a button click.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
if ($(this).text() == "Show options") {
$(".tabs").animate(
  {
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop(0)
  },
  "slow"
 );
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you have to add a setTimeout with at least for me 200ms:

```
setTimeout( function() {$("#DIV_ID").scrollTop(0)}, 200 );
```

Tested with Firefox / Chrome / Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos)
```

Here xpos is Required. The coordinate to scroll to, along the x-axis (horizontal), in pixels

ypos is also Required. The coordinate to scroll to, along the y-axis (vertical), in pixels

Comment: This will scroll the whole window. User needed to scroll just an element, in this case a `<div>`.